# cURL error during making API call. cURL Error Number:[60] SSL certificate prob: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, curl, quickbooks-online

Good Day, I am new to server settings. I am currently using laravel 5.4 to integrate my [quickbooks app](https://github.com/intuit/QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK) on my live server http://qb.dagnum.com/connect but I continue to get this error

```
(1/1) SdkException
cURL error during making API call. cURL Error Number:[60] with error:[SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain]
```

I added the package using 'composer require quickbooks/v3-php-sdk'. the server has SSL certificated Installed as well but still my getting the error.

my code:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;   
use QuickBooksOnline\API\DataService\DataService;

class Auth2Controller extends Controller
 {
  public function index()
   {

        $dataService = DataService::Configure(array(
         'auth_mode' => 'oauth2',
         'ClientID' => "Q0lCkcEshsGMHOEula2r5RKc2yhxvMsYEpKN1lw1WZwyfd1Si6",
         'ClientSecret' => "gE0F9hLgwx9OBzRpNxyOvWJH6L2fIhzAwBugPJHq",
         'accessTokenKey' => 'eyJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2IiwiYWxnIjoiZGlyIn0..4z4Assj4x1qt8H4DtQco6A.nmV2jTxaDMVdFWEUO16q5qhbd5aD6U-U-RYnSNywqg-HPC_3_jvwpMJU1a1S5X-PgPUy60WvVy_8p1awY7kIoFzTV4IhdFLrZpYtBUGCjcsvjxWeOSgP6oCayBEmCv7zzabtgB6vxU46jQqKX2IXYUGPPtyYO64hrgELFR4SKUK6boZiVnh8z19gnvsReKMmIINA3-NgC6QJqMRp6HWgzCa9RuDN9tCtrAK2dy5xmJRNSNgdv_gyg1bfdX4l4b30fLPzFk31fsTT9NTJq9PuGtdTsvUuCj7Hme6HPldD9TKYRXWU8TKrQQrQWEpdlbPr6F3rhP6IdmCv9t1XH_WzF_1IseRUoYhiTUjubig-j8gzwajIdYQTzpJQKJ92QiAEyt8k40WWg0v69hEC0w7WRBuUE-IJ50xWypqS_P28IWt1G14rovZ97soGOteSik-41g1icR2zxfNhXGq7zO7oU5B8r-ej5Pb52T0MCMktgd6y32bqwo2pcEzblL2bZs7DZ7LDx5peY4TIfGW21crTE6xjhRr7LdqB8K505pRqIOP20eaRgwtGHLZ3bdBt1_negw2AGjc409BM0nLzzmODxr3yo-YdGwkcOjm5QgbGAsrnpoSo9tSpxPHoN0vMRneRdsKCd6CZG5M1OIOMuj7spkm442tvwiAMCx2Fh-STG6fMnhOq7l_f8NW_3kscxtF2.obQxJKjPfi1KlaQQ_OUoNg',
         'refreshTokenKey' => "L011509163184Q0K7DT40SVXhJXAfyoj6B6EbSr3Ty64yVvF5A",
         'QBORealmID' => "123145857569084",
         'baseUrl' => "https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com"
      ));

      $dataService->setMinorVersion("9");
      $CompanyInfo = $dataService->getCompanyInfo();
      $error = $dataService->getLastError();

    if ($error != null) {
        echo "The Status code is: " . $error->getHttpStatusCode() . "\n";
        echo "The Helper message is: " . $error->getOAuthHelperError() . "\n";
        echo "The Response message is: " . $error->getResponseBody() . "\n";
        echo "The Intuit Helper message is: IntuitErrorType:{" . $error->getIntuitErrorType() . "} IntuitErrorCode:{" . $error->getIntuitErrorCode() . "} IntuitErrorMessage:{" . $error->getIntuitErrorMessage() . "} IntuitErrorDetail:{" . $error->getIntuitErrorDetail() . "}";
    } 

   }
```

I also saw the curl function

```
private function setSSL(&$curl_opt, $verifySSL){
      if($verifySSL){
          $curl_opt[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = true;
          $curl_opt[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = 2;
          $curl_opt[CURLOPT_CAINFO] = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/OAuth/OAuth2/certs/apiintuitcom.pem"; //Pem certification Key Path
     }
    }
```

tried to replace

```
$curl_opt[CURLOPT_CAINFO] = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/OAuth/OAuth2/certs/apiintuitcom.pem";

to `$curl_opt[CURLOPT_CAINFO] ="/home/servername/public_html/quickbooks_app/resources/cert/cacert.pem";`
```

but I get this error 
    Http Status Code:[401] Http Response Body are null or Empty.

What should I do to fix this please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you go to /vendor/quickbooks/v3-php-sdk/src/Core/HttpClients and edit CurlHttpClient.php

find

```
// $curl_opt[CURLOPT_CAINFO] = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/OAuth/OAuth2/certs/apiintuitcom.pem"; //Pem certification Key Path
```

change it to

```
' $curl_opt[CURLOPT_CAINFO] ="/home/folder/public_html/quickbooks_app/resources/cert/cacert.pem";
```

note: you can put your cacert.pem anywhere just change the address where you link it.

you can get cacert.pem on this site https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

Answer (score 1):

I've dropped the `apiintuitcom.pem` file that comes with the SDK and started using the `cacert.pem` that you can find on [PHP_OAuth2.0](https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/OAuth2_PHP/blob/master/OAuth_2/Certificate/cacert.pem) example app. I was also using a wrong **baseUrl** but I changed with yours. That fixed the bug for me. My `setSSL` method looks like this now:

```
private function setSSL(&$curl_opt, $verifySSL){
  if($verifySSL){
      $curl_opt[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = true;
      $curl_opt[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = 2;
      $curl_opt[CURLOPT_CAINFO] = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/OAuth/OAuth2/certs/cacert.pem"; //Pem certification Key Path
  }
}
```

My `$dataService` is pretty much the same as yours.