# Quickbooks Integration SSL Local Issuer issue

Tags: ssl, integration, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I have integrated Quickbooks invoice feature on my website.
But I am facing issue of SSL Local Issuer.
Here is the error details:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught QuickBooksOnline\API\Exception\SdkException: [0]: cURL error during making API call. cURL Error Number:[60] with error:[SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate]...
```

Could someone advise me, how to fix this issue?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did u enabled SSL for your website?(Quickbooks app will communicate with a secure site) this link will help to solve your issue : 
[PHP cURL error code 60](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114371/php-curl-error-code-60/21114601#21114601)

QB Library file edit link
[cURL error during making API call. cURL Error Number:[60] SSL certificate prob: self signed certificate in certificate chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45472928/curl-error-during-making-api-call-curl-error-number60-ssl-certificate-prob)

Answer (score 0):

Searched a lot about this. Finally, I talked to QBO support for this.

They told me that Sometimes when we install SSL certificate on the server so it conflicts with the API inbuilt certificates. And that is the reason why the API throw SSL certificate not exist error on SSL certified website.

So they suggested my best comment out the API inbuilt certificate verification syntax.

And to achieve this we just need to comment out line with verifySSL() calling. And this is in the Same file mentioned above.

But Thank you for the help on this. I really appreciate it a lot.